# Troubleshooting Google maps JavaScript API / navigator.geolocation error that wont add a marker location inside a park

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, maps, navigator

Im trying to get my geolocation to show inside a nearby park/conservancy. In this instance when im on the local hiking trail. When using the Google maps Javascript API and the navigator.geolocation from the browser if I'm walking in the street or anywhere inside the typical google maps neighborhood (the grayish areas on google maps) the results are accurate but the second i step into the park/conservancy (a green area) the location stops exactly at the street as if there were a forcefield. The location marker will follow my route along the street like a mime as i walk down the trail but will not cross the plane of the park.

I personally am at a loss as this even happened when i used the Google "find your location" example from the documents for the API. So for this i submit their example as i have followed it to the fullest but wonder if anyone knows a workaround to get my location to show accurately in the park or a reason to why this might be happening?

Phone settings that I have tried on my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra are:
WI-FI off, Bluetooth Off, WI-Fi Scanning off and on, Bluetooth scanning off and on.

```
let map: google.maps.Map, infoWindow: google.maps.InfoWindow;

function initMap(): void {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement, {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 6,
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  const locationButton = document.createElement("button");

  locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
  locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);

  locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position: GeolocationPosition) => {
          const pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };

          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        },
        () => {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter()!);
        }
      );
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter()!);
    }
  });
}

function handleLocationError(
  browserHasGeolocation: boolean,
  infoWindow: google.maps.InfoWindow,
  pos: google.maps.LatLng
) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation
      ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
      : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
  );
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```